# Django Rest + React + Flutter: how to restrict domain origin of requests

Tags: reactjs, django, flutter, django-rest-framework, django-settings

I am currently building a web + mobile application.

**My front end** is developed using React and Axios (for API call requests). It is served directly by vercel on mydomain.com

**My Mobile App** is developed using the Flutter

**My back end** is developed using Django and Django Rest. It is served with apache2 on api.mydomain.com. It only serves API endpoints.

So the front-end, Mobile app, and back-end are separated.

**I would like only my front-end (mydomain.com) and flutter app to be able to make API requests to my Django Rest backend.
I would like to prevent any other domains, any clients such as postman, insomnia, curl, or any script to make API requests to my backend.**

I have already set CORS in Django Rest. However, I can still make requests to the backend using curl or any other client.

**Do you have any idea of what I could do to achieve this?**

Thanks a lot in advance for your answers.

Comment: Have you set the CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST and CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS in your settings.py?

Comment: yes, I have already set all of them

Answer (score 0):

`CORS` is enforced only by web browsers to prevent leaking information to unrelated pages that might request it. You need some kind of access control, either by authenticating the caller or limiting access to the endpoint.

Checking the Host header with `get_host()` may offer sufficient protection, depending on your server setup.

`get_host()` will tell you the value of the `Host` header in the request, which is data provided by the client so could be manipulated in any way. The `Host` header is an integral part of `HTTP 1.1` in allowing multiple domains to be hosted at a single address so you might be able to depend on your server rejecting requests that aren't actually arriving from localhost with a matching header, but it's difficult to be certain.

It would likely be more reliable to check the client's network address and reject requests from all clients except those that are specifically allowed.
Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702217/how-to-get-a-client-ip-address-in-django-using-python) too.